# Doxygen document preprocessor-generated code

Tags: c++, c, doxygen

I have some code that looks like this:

```cpp
enum ID {
  Opt_Invalid = 0,
#define OPTION(id, ...) Opt_##id
#include "path/to/Options.inc"
  Opt_None
#undef OPTION
}
```

and in `Options.inc` :

```cpp
#ifdef OPTION
OPTION(optionA, ...)
OPTION(optionB, ...)
#endif
```

I would like Doxygen to document the enum after the macro is evaluated, like:

```cpp
enum ID {Opt_Invalid, Opt_optionA, Opt_optionB, Opt_None}
```

Instead i only get:

```cpp
enum ID {Opt_Invalid, Opt_None}
```

I am currently using the following configuration:

```
INPUT                   = @PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR@/docs/doxygen/index.md \
                          @PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR@/include \
                          @PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR@/lib/
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY        = @CMAKE_BINARY_DIR@/docs/doxygen
INCLUDE_PATH            = @PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR@/include
SEARCH_INCLUDES         = YES
FILE_PATTERNS           = *.h   \
                          *.cpp \
                          *.inc
RECURSIVE               = YES
EXTRACT_ALL             = YES
EXTENSION_MAPPING       = .inc=C++
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING    = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION         = YES
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to document macro-generated classes with Doxygen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485462/how-to-document-macro-generated-classes-with-doxygen)

Comment: Doxygen has had problems with X-macros in the past. Some things to try: 1. Make sure `inc` file ends with newline. 2. Ensure doxygen version is 1.9 or newer.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? What is there in your doxygen configuration different from the default configuration (`doxygen -x Doxyfile`)? Did you have a look at `EXTENSION_MAPPING` as by default `inc` code  is handled by the PHP (sub) parser in doxygen.

Comment: @albert I have updated the question to include the Doxyfile

Comment: @user694733 I tried with Doxygen 1.9.4 but the result is the same

Comment: Cross posted to https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/9133